# Cloud Foundry map Users with spaces, organizations and role collections

Tags: api, cloud-foundry

I have cloud foundry organizations and spaces in these organizations. To check which Users is in which space I wanted to access the API via the cloud controller v3: https://v3-apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/version/3.91.0/

With the Api I can for example read out all organizations or all spaces but I think the API does not provide information about which user is in which organization, space or role collection.

Therefore my question is, if there is a way to see which person is in which organization, space or role collection or if I have to use something else.

If I have to use something else, could you provide some information about that (i.e. a link).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want [Roles](https://v3-apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/version/3.91.0/#list-roles).

> Roles control access to resources in organizations and spaces. Roles are assigned to users.

This is what you set with `cf set-org-role` or `cf set-space-role`.

You have the following valid roles:

- organization_user
- organization_auditor
- organization_manager
- organization_billing_manager
- space_auditor
- space_developer
- space_manager

Comment: Did I understand your answer correctly: if I now retrieve all roles I can see what spaces and organizations these roles have access to and all users which have this role. Therefore I can say that this user belongs to the space/organization ?

Comment: I'm not really sure if I can get the org members from this method or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: If you have a user, you can use this to get the user's org & space roles. You can filter on org and space guid's, if you'd rather do it that way. It's just a mapping though. If you have one, you can look up the other. I suppose you could load them all and sift through as well, but only for short periods since those could change at any moment.

Comment: The important thing is that there is no strict org or space "membership", it's just roles that define what orgs and spaces you have permissions to view and interact with. You can have roles to access any number of orgs & spaces.

Comment: i think I got what you mean, but a problem I'm facing is that there are duplicates of roles with the same id and informationen and I'm not sure why they exist. Do you know why?

Comment: I do not, but that seems like a reasonable question. I would suggest you make a new question and post details, like an actual example as a new SO question.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to call "/v3/roles" endpoint and filter based on userid
To get the userid you can call the "/v3/users" and filter based on username.
Than You will need to iterate over all the roles, and extract org, space etc.
I found this post
https://guyfromit.com/post/cf-userroles/